# Bodmas question.

Tags: arithmetic

Someone told me that the answer to 100 - 26 ÷ 2 + 8 was 95 (not 79 which is what I thought it was).  Could they be right?

Comment: You've evaluated $100-(26/2+8)$.

Comment: Presumably by subtracting the eight as well.  I assume that he went by saying $100-26\div 2 + 8 = 100-13+8$  From here, applying addition before subtraction would yield $100-(13+8)=100-21=79$.  What is often overlooked when talking about addition and subtraction is that they are of the same importance and should be carried out left-to-right.  $a-b+c = a+(-b)+c$ not $a-(b+c)$

Answer (score 1):

They are right.  By order of operations, the first operation you perform is division, so you divide $26\div 2=13$.  You then add and subtract $$100-13+8$$ from left to right: $100-13=87$ and $87+8=95$.

Note that the acronym BODMAS is misleading, because it suggests you do addition before subtraction (and division before multiplication).  This is *not true*.  Rather, you perform addition and subtraction at the same time, going from left to right as I did here (and similarly you perform multiplication and division at the same time).

Comment: Ah I got it wrong, sorry.  It was 26 ÷ 2.

Comment: @RichardSewell: I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Do you not use the BODMAS rule after you divide?  I thought it would be 26 ÷ 2 to get you 100 - 13 + 8.  Do you not then do 13 + 8 because that comes before subtraction?

Comment: See the latest update to my answer--I figured out how you got $79$ and added something to address that as you were commenting :).

Comment: Alternatively, simply write all in terms of addition (after the division): $$100 +-13 + 8$$ Then you can add in whatever order you please.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that up!  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is even 99.333...
By applying Bodmas, you consider first the division. so -26/3=-8.666..., then you add 8 to it and 100. Hence, the final answer should be 99.333...

ok, the question is 110-26/2+8.
The answer then is 95.
-26/2=13, 100-13+8= 95

Comment: pay attention to updates to the post

Comment: Too late...you posted this after the OP updated the question.